# Querying large amount of data processed by Hive

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, bigdata

Say I have around 10-20GB of data in HDFS as a Hive table. This has been obtained after several Map-Reduce jobs and JOIN over two separate datasets. I need to make this Queryable to the user. What options do I have?

1. Use [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) to transfer data from HDFS to an RDS like Postgresql. But I want to avoid spending so much time on data transfer. I just tested HDFS->RDS in the same AWS region using Sqoop, and 800mb of data takes 4-8 minutes. So you can imagine ~60gb of data would be pretty unmanagable. This would be my last resort.
2. Query Hive directly from my Webserver as per user request. I haven't ever head of Hive being used like this so I'm skeptical about this. This struck me because I just found out you can query hive tables remotely after some port forwarding on the EMR cluster. But being new to big(ish) data I'm not quite sure about the risks associated with this. Is it commonplace to do this?
3. Some other solution - How do people usually do this kind of thing? Seems like a pretty common task.

Just for completeness sake, my data looks like this:

```
id     time             cat1    cat2    cat3    metrics[200]
A123   1234212133        12     ABC      24      4,55,231,34,556,123....(~200)
.
.
.
```

(time is epoch)

And my Queries look like this:

`select cat1, corr(metrics[2],metrics[3]),corr(metrics[2],metrics[4]),corr(metrics[2],metrics[5]),corr(metrics[2],metrics[6]) from tablename group by cat1;`

I *need* the correlation function, which is why I've chosen postgresql over MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have correlation function in [Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)):

> corr(col1, col2)

Returns the Pearson coefficient of correlation of a pair of a numeric columns in the group.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, but I mainly wanted to know whether using Hive like that is good practice or not...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply connect to a hiveserver port via odbc and execute queries.
Here is an example: 
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/connectors/hive/odbc/hive-odbc-v2-5-10.html

Comment: I realize it's possible, but is it good practice? I've never heard of Hive being used like that.

Comment: Sure. I think this is the main way Hive is used. Hive should be exposed to users and machines to execute ETL and analytics and much more from remote servers. Users usually access it either by Hue or any querying software like DBVisualizer that support ODBC and JDBC. Also, using JDBC you can access it from Java and create software that implements ETL jobs over hive. All of the above is very common.

Comment: Take a look at this though: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-WhatHiveIsNOT. Says `Hive is not designed for online transaction processing and does not offer real-time queries`. Thoughts?

Comment: This means hive doesn't support transactions (now in 0.13 it kinda does) and as long as you are using map-reduce this is correct you will not get realtime queries as there is a constant overhead. This doesn't mean that you shouldn't query, just that it is build for more analytical and robust queries

Answer (score 0):

Hive User Experience (hue) has a Beeswax query editor designed specifically for the purpose of exposing Hive to end users who are comfortable with SQL.  This way they can potentially run ad-hoc queries against the data residing in Hive without needing to move it elsewhere.  You can see an example of the Beeswax Query Editor here: http://demo.gethue.com/beeswax/#query

Will that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

What i can understand from the question posted above is you have some data (20GB ) which you have stored in hdfs and using hive. Now you want to access that data to perform some kind of statistics functions like correlation and others.

- You have functions in hive that perform correlation.
- Otherwise you can directly connect R to hive using RHive or even excel to hive using datasource.
- The other solution is installing hue which comes with hive editors where you can directly query the hive.